# How to get and set the cursor position from summernote editor using javascript

Tags: javascript, position, editor, richtextbox, summernote

I can't find any documentation for how you would get the position of the cursor in the summernote editor. I know how to do this in a normal textarea, but in summernote the editor renders as a div and I'm therefore lost.

Does anyone got some ideas on how to solve this or is this simply not possible in the current version of summernote. I'm open for hacks.